# zClip works in JSfiddle but not on my system?

Tags: jquery, jsfiddle, zclip

I have this code on JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/f4gZA/948/

Following is the HTML code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
 <html>
   <head>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.zclip.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/js/jquery.zclip.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
      <title>Form Builder</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <textarea cols="65" rows="19" name="textarea" id="textarea">Hello World! I am copied...
      </textarea>

      <button id='copy-button'>copy</button>
   </body>
 </html>
```

Folowing is the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#copy-button").zclip({
path: "http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/js/ZeroClipboard.swf",
copy: function() {
    return $('#textarea').text();
}
 });
});
```

It works perfectly on JSfiddle, but does not work on my computer at all.

Please explain!!!

Comment: sorry actually i pasted the jsfiddle by mistake.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: No errors. When i click on copy button nothing happens.

Comment: weird :/ then i don't know what the problem could be.

Comment: Finally, got it working.

Comment: There was some issue with the path. Anyway... Thanks @Anton for help!

Answer (score 0):

Above mentioned code is correct.

**Note that:** zclip only works on server.

*So you need to run it on localhost or server*.

Hope to help you :)